# FFMPEG how to combine -filter_complex with h264 and output to stdout

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, pipe, h.264

I need to stream some ffmpeg output that is generated with ffmpeg (audio to video); for this I'm using *-filter_complex avectorscope*.

I am testing the pipe with ffplay, something like this works:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f h264 - | ffplay -
```

and something like this also works fine (writing to a file):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]avectorscope=s=1920x1080,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 avectorscope.mp4
```

But what I really need is something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]avectorscope=s=1920x1080,format=yuv420p[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -f h264 | ffplay -
```

but when I try that I get this error:

**Automatic encoder selection failed for output stream #0:1. Default encoder for format h264 (codec none) is probably disabled. Please choose an encoder manually.
Error selecting an encoder for stream 0:1
pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input**

So I can encode it to a file but not encode it to a pipe with the same flags.

I also tried with other format (-f flv and -f mpegts) and they also work (for ffplay), but it doesn't work with other tools that require h264 stream as input.

I hope someone can help!

Comment: I habitually use `-f matroska - | ffplay -i -` as matroska seems, so far, to cope with anything I throw at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-f h264` represents a raw H.264 bitstream so audio can't be included.

Use a container with multiplexing e.g. `nut`

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]avectorscope=s=1920x1080,format=yuv420p[v]" \ -map "[v]" -map 0:a -vcodec libx264 -f nut | ffplay -f nut -`

Comment: This also works for ffplay fine, but not for my other application, it keeps telling me (data is not a H264 bitstream) when I pipe that output to it, also why does it has sound when I do something like this: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f h264 - | ffplay - ?

Comment: Then use your original command (3rd) but remove `-map 0:a`

Comment: sure, removing -map 0:a works, but it also removes the sound, isn't there a way to get it with the audio the same as when the video is already encoded? ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f h264 - ?

Comment: The other application wants "a H264 bitstream" which can't carry audio.

Comment: yes I just see that it's not doing it how is supposed to, but I found another way thanks to your idea, but instead of nut I'm using flv which is also allowed with some libraries, thank you!